# Form Resetting is not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to reset the form after calling an ajax function.
This is the code i gave in the jquery:

```
$("#frm_silder").reset();
```

Here `frm_silder` is the id of form. But when I'm using this code i got an eorror message like this.

```
$("#frm_silder").reset is not a function
```

In my html i give the id to form like this:

```
<form name="frm_silder" id="frm_silder" method="post">
```

So what is the problem in my code?

Comment: have you added or imported  jquery library on the page

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In jQuery

```
$('#frm_silder')[0].reset();
```

in Javascript

```
document.getElementById('frm_silder').reset()
```

Comment: Thaks, woks for me too.

Comment: And for me too!

Answer (score 4):

You need to reset each element individually. Jquery does not have a function `reset()` that works on a form. `reset()` is a Javascript function that works on form elements only. You can however define a new jquery function `reset()` that iterates through all form elements and calls the javascript `reset()` on each of them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#reset').reset();
    });
});

 // we define a function reset
jQuery.fn.reset = function () {
  $(this).each (function() { this.reset(); });
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KdvTx/4/)**

Alternatively, if you don't want to define a function, you can iterate through the form elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('#reset').each(function() {
            this.reset();
        });
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KdvTx/6/)**

**[Source](http://www.codigomanso.com/en/2008/12/resetear-un-formulario-con-jquery/)**

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `reset()` method because JavaScript already has one. Calling `reset()` on a form element (see accepted answer above) will reset all form fields. Your method works in most cases, unless the form has a File input field. Your code will not work in all browsers in that case. The only sure way to clear a File input field is to use JavaScript's `reset` method.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the solution given by @sameera. But it still throw me error.

I changed the reset to the following

```
$("form#frm_silder")[0].reset();
```

Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new { area = "MyArea" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "" }))
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyData, new { @class = "col-form-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyData, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset"> Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Then clear the form:

```
    $('.btn:reset').click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('form').find("input").each(function(i, v) {
            $(this).val("");
        });
    });
```