# Form resetting is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, reset

I'm using the following code to reset the form fields.

```
document.getElementById("form1").reset();//form1 is the form id.
```

It is not working. I also tried with `JQuery`. Even JQuery also not working.

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
$('form1')[0].reset();
});
```

My html code is

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
<h3>Personal Information</h3>
<h4>Name</h4>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" maxlength=50 size=11/>
<input type="text" id="mname" name="mname" maxlength=15 size=8/>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" maxlength=50 size=11/>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" onclick="Reset()"/>
</form>
```

I'm following [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_reset). Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ty9rU/). Can you please explain the mistake?

Comment: Why dont you use a reset button `<input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">`

Comment: Don't follow w3schools. Please. It teaches you terrible practices.

Comment: @kapa why? can you say

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: They masquerade themselves like an authority (lots of people confuse them with w3c), but they teach outdated and bad practices in their tutorials. For me, it took some time to relearn stuff and lose some bad habits - I want to warn others who are about to commit the same mistake I did as a beginner.

Comment: Check this link [Reset Form](http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/javascript-clear-form/javascript-clear-form-example.html)

Comment: You just override reset function with your input element with reset id! change id of your button and that is all...  [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/ty9rU/18/)

Comment: @Givi: That and changing `onLoad` to `no wrap - in <head>` (although that's only specific to the jsFiddle example).

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you're right!

Comment: Please visit follow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937285/form-resetting-is-not-working-using-jquery/57264409#57264409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved my issue. the problem is `"id=reset"`. Because it overrides the `reset` method . I changed it to `id="reset1"`. Now it is working

Answer (score 21):

The problem here is that you've set the `id` of your button to `"reset"`. This automatically overwrites the built-in [reset method of the form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset).

The solution is to use a different `id` attribute for your button.

So instead of:

```html
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Use something like:

```html
<input type="button" id="reset-button" value="Reset" />
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ty9rU/16/).

Comment: *"It is worth noting that all attributes need to be quoted in HTML (even numbers)"* **That's incorrect**: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes. Attributes must only be quoted if they contain specific characters (such as a space or a `>` character). See the link for more information.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. I guess it's only applies to XML then. But still, it doesnt harm if you quote values. Edited it anyway.

Comment: Yep, in XML (and XHTML for that matter) you have to put attribute values in double quotes. But HTML is a less strict markup language.

Answer (score 4):

Have you  simply try this : [Reset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_reset)

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
```

Comment: this is not an answer to my question. according to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp The reset() method resets the values of all elements in a form (same as clicking the Reset button).

Answer (score 3):

If your objective is only to reset the form, you could try this:

```
<input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" onclick="this.form.reset();"/>
```

Comment: this is the most simplest solution

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your seleting $('form1') as in an element with a tag name of form1, while i think you actually want to select it by the id:

```
$('#form1')[0].reset();
```

Comment: it is the same as `document.getElementById("form1").reset();` which OP said that it didn't work. Why? I don't know...

Comment: Hi, sorry i missed the fiddle link.

Comment: Ok, check my new answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285970/javascript-reset-form-is-not-working/20286108?noredirect=1#answer-20286356

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, the correct selector is :

```
$('#form1') // Select with ID
```

OR

```
$('form[name=form1]') // Select with name
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with getting a reference to the element via `getElementById`?

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ty9rU/12/).

Why vanilla js isn't working:

You don't have...

```
document.getElementById("form1").reset();//form1 is the form id.
```

...within a reset function. You could do this:

```
function Reset() {
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();//form1 is the form id.
}
```

Why jQuery isn't working:

You don't need to do all that you're doing. It's much more simple than that. Also, look at your 'form1' selector. You should likely add '#form1' instead. jQuery selects are different than the getElementByID function. As you can probably assume by the name, the getElementByID function is already getting the element by the ID; however with jQuery you have to specify those things. Also, don't really need the onClick attribute with jquery.

Comment: Uh? I can clearly see `function Reset() { document.getElementById("form1").reset(); }` in [his fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ty9rU/).

Comment: Look at the difference between his fiddle and the code posted here. Specifically, OP calls reset() here and formReset() in the fiddle.

Comment: Are we talking about the same fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net/ty9rU/) I don't see where `formReset()` is called. But that's not my point: You claimed that the statement `document.getElementById(...)` was not inside the `Reset` function, which it clearly is.

Comment: Look at the onClick attribute in the post above, not in the fiddle. That's where the confusion happened. The fiddle and the code above don't match.

Comment: It was changed during our conversation.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's safe to assume the OP tried to run the code that is in the fiddle, not in his post. *edit:* You mean the code in the post was changed? No, the last edit didn't change the code. And if you mean the fiddle, it cannot be changed either. Anyways, I said what I had to say :)

Comment: Ahh you're right. I was staring at the w3school Tryit. I just woke up. I'm going back to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, see my new jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ty9rU/17/
So i renamed the button to `reset_btn`

Basicly you had an element called reset inside the form, and that caused the issue.

Comment: OP already figured this out 6 min before you posted your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20286240/218196.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm confused, How it overrides?

Comment: @ling.s: Because browser vendors thought it would be a good idea to add form control elements as properties to their form element, with their ID as property name (if existed). As you can see this is a rather confusing behavior because it will overwrite other existing properties of the form element.